# need setProperty syntax for XMP object

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-indesign, extendscript, xmp

I am randomly generating `DocumentID` and `InstanceID`, but facing problem in  setting property `DocumentID` and `InstanceID` to the xmp object.

How can I set the generated `DocumentID` and `InstanceID` to my `allXMP`?

```js
var xmpFile = new XMPFile(linkFilepath, XMPConst.FILE_INDESIGN, XMPConst.OPEN_FOR_UPDATE);
var allXMP = xmpFile.getXMP();

// Retrieve values from external links XMP.
var documentID = allXMP.getProperty(XMPConst.NS_XMP_MM, 'DocumentID', XMPConst.STRING);
var instanceID = allXMP.getProperty(XMPConst.NS_XMP_MM, 'InstanceID', XMPConst.STRING);

documentID =  randomString(32);
instanceID = randomString(32);

// ???? Here I need to set DocumentID and InstanceID to allXMP

if (xmpFile.canPutXMP(allXMP)) {     
    xmpFile.putXMP(allXMP);    
    xmpFile.closeFile(XMPConst.CLOSE_UPDATE_SAFELY);     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the [`setProperty()`](https://javascript-tools-guide.readthedocs.io/scripting-xmp/xmpscript-object-reference.html?highlight=setProperty()#setproperty) method in the *AdobeXMPScript* library to create and set the value for `DocumentID` and `InstanceID`

Below are a couple of helper functions for adding a `DocumentID` and `InstanceID`.

```js
// Note: This function works on macOS only
function generateUUID() {
  var cmd = 'do shell script "uuidgen | tr -d " & quoted form of "-"';
  return app.doScript(cmd, ScriptLanguage.applescriptLanguage);
}

// Add an XMP property and Value.
function addXmpPropertyAndValue(filePath, xmpProperty, xmpValue) {
  var xmpFile = new XMPFile(filePath, XMPConst.FILE_UNKNOWN, XMPConst.OPEN_FOR_UPDATE);
  var allXMP = xmpFile.getXMP();

  allXMP.setProperty(XMPConst.NS_XMP_MM, xmpProperty, xmpValue);

  if (xmpFile.canPutXMP(allXMP)) {
    xmpFile.putXMP(allXMP);
  }

  xmpFile.closeFile(XMPConst.CLOSE_UPDATE_SAFELY);

  // Useful for testing purposes....
  alert('Added: ' + xmpProperty + '\n' +
      'value: ' + xmpValue + '\n\n' +
      'Path: ' + filePath, 'Updated XMP', false);
}
```

To add an `instanceID` invoke the `addXmpPropertyAndValue` function as follows:

```js
// The `linkFilepath` argument should be the filepath to the Link you want to update
addXmpPropertyAndValue(linkFilepath, 'InstanceID', 'xmp.iid:' + generateUUID());
```

To add an `DocumentID` invoke the `addXmpPropertyAndValue` function as follows:

```js
// The `linkFilepath` argument should be the filepath to the Link you want to update
addXmpPropertyAndValue(linkFilepath, 'DocumentID', 'xmp.did:' + generateUUID());
```

---

**Additional Note:**

When generating the value(s) for `DocumentID` and `InstanceID` the guidelines state:

> *An ID should be guaranteed to be globally unique (in practical terms, this means that the probability of a collision is so remote as to be effectively impossible). Typically 128- or 144-bit numbers are used, encoded as hexadecimal strings*

<sup>*The excerpt (above) can be found on *page 19* of [*Partner's guide to XMP for Dynamic Media*](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/xmp/pdfs/DynamicMediaXMPPartnerGuide.pdf) (PDF)*</sup>

Unfortunately, *ExtendScript* does not provide a built-in feature to generate a globally unique identifier (GUID). However macOS does include [`uuidgen`](https://ss64.com/osx/uuidgen.html) which is a command-line utility/library for
generating unique identifiers (UUID/GUID).

The helper function (above):

```js
function generateUUID() {
  var cmd = 'do shell script "uuidgen | tr -d " & quoted form of "-"';
  return app.doScript(cmd, ScriptLanguage.applescriptLanguage);
}
```

runs on macOS only. It utilizes AppleScript to run the `uuidgen` command.

*You may want to generate the identifier this way instead of your current `randomString(32)` function call.*