# need to add documentId and instanceId tags for .indd meta info after generating missing documentId and InstanceIds for the links

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign, extendscript, xmp

Using `ExtendScript`, I am updating the missing `DocumentId` and `InstanceId` for the links of an Indesign (`.indd`) file,  using the reference code at [need setProperty syntax for XMP object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56257793/need-setproperty-syntax-for-xmp-object/56258622#56258622). This is working fine and updating the each links missing `DoumentId` and `InstanceId` properly. But the problem now I am facing is that, the `.indd` file itself has meta info where these newly generated `DocumentId` and `InstanceId` are missing for that particular links.

Please refer the below Meta Info of the `.indd` file with four resources for better understanding. Here it has four resources two `.psd` files and two `.ai` files. The `.indd` file meta info contains `<stRef:instanceID>` and `<stRef:documentID>` for the two `.ai` resources, where as these tags (`<stRef:instanceID>` and `<stRef:documentID>` ) are missing for the other two `.psd` resources. Even after generating missing `DocumentId` and `InstanceId` for .psd files, in the .indd file meta info for these two resources these two tags `<stRef:instanceID>` and `<stRef:documentID>`, are still missing. How can I update DocumentId and InstanceId of these missing links even in `.indd` file meta info?

```xml
<xmpMM:Manifest>
  <rdf:Bag>
    <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
      <stMfs:linkForm>ReferenceStream</stMfs:linkForm>
      <xmpMM:placedXResolution>300.00</xmpMM:placedXResolution>
      <xmpMM:placedYResolution>300.00</xmpMM:placedYResolution>
      <xmpMM:placedResolutionUnit>Inches</xmpMM:placedResolutionUnit>
      <stMfs:reference rdf:parseType="Resource">
        <stRef:lastURL>file:///Users/superadmin/Downloads/266x165mm_VPA_WS_SP_M-1F/Links/6604_RGB.psd</stRef:lastURL>
      </stMfs:reference>
    </rdf:li>
    <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
      <stMfs:linkForm>ReferenceStream</stMfs:linkForm>
      <xmpMM:placedXResolution>72.00</xmpMM:placedXResolution>
      <xmpMM:placedYResolution>72.00</xmpMM:placedYResolution>
      <xmpMM:placedResolutionUnit>Inches</xmpMM:placedResolutionUnit>
      <stMfs:reference rdf:parseType="Resource">
        <stRef:lastURL>file:///Users/superadmin/Downloads/266x165mm_VPA_WS_SP_M-1F/Links/Silver_001_RGB.psd</stRef:lastURL>
      </stMfs:reference>
    </rdf:li>
    <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
      <stMfs:linkForm>ReferenceStream</stMfs:linkForm>
      <xmpMM:placedXResolution>72.00</xmpMM:placedXResolution>
      <xmpMM:placedYResolution>72.00</xmpMM:placedYResolution>
      <xmpMM:placedResolutionUnit>Inches</xmpMM:placedResolutionUnit>
      <stMfs:reference rdf:parseType="Resource">
        <stRef:instanceID>uuid:d34cbf16-4c87-4344-a0db-6cf67ffe6f84</stRef:instanceID>
        <stRef:documentID>xmp.did:fd9d95eb-fe2d-4fca-92a2-1906d98a10f4</stRef:documentID>
        <stRef:lastURL>file:///Users/superadmin/Downloads/266x165mm_VPA_WS_SP_M-1F/Links/bkgd_rgb_en.ai</stRef:lastURL>
    </stMfs:reference>
    </rdf:li>
    <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
      <stMfs:linkForm>ReferenceStream</stMfs:linkForm>
      <xmpMM:placedXResolution>72.00</xmpMM:placedXResolution>
      <xmpMM:placedYResolution>72.00</xmpMM:placedYResolution>
      <xmpMM:placedResolutionUnit>Inches</xmpMM:placedResolutionUnit>
      <stMfs:reference rdf:parseType="Resource">
        <stRef:instanceID>uuid:afd031b3-018a-434a-989f-c0e35ff0cebb</stRef:instanceID>
        <stRef:documentID>xmp.did:f4cbc476-258f-4807-8734-d8afc200fbfb</stRef:documentID>
        <stRef:lastURL>file:///Users/superadmin/Downloads/266x165mm_VPA_WS_SP_M-1F/Links/bax_logo_whitebox_cmyk.ai</stRef:lastURL>
      </stMfs:reference>
    </rdf:li>
  </rdf:Bag>
</xmpMM:Manifest>
```

Comment: Hi Madasu K, I have a couple of questions.... **1)** Are you updating the link status in the inDesign document after you add the missing `DocumentID` and `InstanceID` to the link, and are you doing this before you obtain the new `.indd` meta that is currently not showing `<stRef:instanceID>` and `<stRef:documentID>` in the `<rdf:Bag>`? **2)** If you are updating the link status in the InDesign document (as per question 1), are you doing this manually via InDesign's _Links_ panel, or are you updating the link status programmatically via your script?

Comment: Hi RobC, 1) No, initially when I open .indd at that time only I am clicking Update links in the panel, not after generating missing DocumentId and InstanceId. 2) I am updating links via InDesign's Link panel. Now my requirement is after I generate missing documentId and InstanceId for the links, I need to add those relevant tags in <rdf:Bag> inside  <xmpMM:Manifest> tag of .indd manifest info file.

Comment: Small clarification there are multiple </rdf:Bag> tags for each link in .indd manifest info file.  The </rdf:Bag> I have mentioned in my question are those appear inside </xmpMM:Manifest> tag. Remaining  </rdf:Bag> tags outside </xmpMM:Manifest> tag, does not concern to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue of the `<stRef:instanceID>` and `<stRef:documentID>` in the `<xmpMM:Manifest>`'s `<rdf:Bag>` not being reflected in the `indd` files meta is encountered when either:

- Manually updating the links by clicking *"Update Links"* in InDesign's Links palette.
- Or not updating the links status at all.

You need to programmatically update the InDesign links status via your script after adding the missing `DocumentID` and `InstanceID` to the linked resource. You can utilize the following function to do this:

```js
/**
 * Update all document links whose state is outdated.
 * @param {Object} doc - A reference to the .indd to update.
 */
function updateOutdatedLinks(doc) {
  for (var i = 0, len = doc.links.length; i < len; i++) {
    var link = doc.links[i];
    if (link.status === LinkStatus.LINK_OUT_OF_DATE) {
      link.update();
    }
  }
}
```

---

**script.jsx**

Below is a full working version that will add any missing `DocumentID` and/or `InstanceID` to the relevant links, and then update it's status in the `.indd`

```js
#target indesign

$.level=0;

// Warn if there are no documents open.
if (!app.documents.length) {
  alert('Open a document and try again.', 'Missing Document', false);
  exit();
}

var doc = app.activeDocument;

/**
 * Loads the AdobeXMPScript library.
 * @returns {Boolean} True if the library loaded successfully, otherwise false.
 */
function loadXMPLibrary() {
  if (!ExternalObject.AdobeXMPScript) {
    try {
      ExternalObject.AdobeXMPScript = new ExternalObject('lib:AdobeXMPScript');
    } catch (e) {
      alert('Failed loading AdobeXMPScript library\n' + e.message, 'Error', true);
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

/**
 * Checks the status of all Indesign links, and exits if the state is not OK.
 * @param {Object} doc - A reference to the .indd to check.
 * @returns {Boolean} True if the state of all links are OK, otherwise false.
 */
function linksStatusCheck(doc) {
  for (var i = 0, len = doc.links.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (doc.links[i].status !== LinkStatus.NORMAL) {
      alert('The status of all links must be OK \nPlease update link status ' +
          'via the Links panel and try again', 'Link Status', true);
      exit();
    }
  }
  return true;
}

/**
 * Generate a unique identifier (UUID/GUID). Note this runs on macOS only.
 * @returns {String} - The generated unique identifier.
 */
function generateUUID() {
  var cmd = 'do shell script "uuidgen | tr -d " & quoted form of "-"';
  return app.doScript(cmd, ScriptLanguage.applescriptLanguage);
}

/**
 * Add an XMP property and value to a given file.
 * @param {String} filePath - Path to the file/asset to add the XMP metadata.
 * @param {String} xmpProperty - Name of the XMP property.
 * @param {String} xmpValue - Value to assign to the XMP property.
 */
function addXmpPropertyAndValue(filePath, xmpProperty, xmpValue) {
  var xmpFile = new XMPFile(filePath, XMPConst.FILE_UNKNOWN, XMPConst.OPEN_FOR_UPDATE);
  var xmp = xmpFile.getXMP();

  xmp.setProperty(XMPConst.NS_XMP_MM, xmpProperty, xmpValue);

  if (xmpFile.canPutXMP(xmp)) {
    xmpFile.putXMP(xmp);
  }

  xmpFile.closeFile(XMPConst.CLOSE_UPDATE_SAFELY);
}

/**
 * Add an `instanceID` to the XMP packet of a file/asset.
 * @param {String} filePath - Path to the file/asset to add the XMP metadata.
 * @param {String} uuid - The unique identifier (UUID/GUID) value to add.
 */
function addInstanceID(filePath, uuid) {
  addXmpPropertyAndValue(filePath, 'InstanceID', 'xmp.iid:' + uuid);
}

/**
 * Add an `documentID` to the XMP packet of a file/asset.
 * @param {String} filePath - Path to the file/asset to add the XMP metadata.
 * @param {String} uuid - The unique identifier (UUID/GUID) value to add.
 */
function addDocumentID(filePath, uuid) {
  addXmpPropertyAndValue(filePath, 'DocumentID', 'xmp.did:' + uuid);
  addXmpPropertyAndValue(filePath, 'OriginalDocumentID', 'xmp.did:' + uuid);
}

/**
 * Adds both `instanceID` and `documentID` to the XMP packet of a file/asset.
 * Note: Both properties share the same unique identifier (UUID/GUID).
 * @param {String} filePath - Path to the file/asset to add the XMP metadata.
 * @param {String} uuid - The unique identifier (UUID/GUID) value to add.
 */
function addDocumentIDAndInstanceID(filePath) {
  var uuid = generateUUID();
  addInstanceID(filePath, uuid);
  addDocumentID(filePath, uuid);
}

/**
 * Checks both XMP properties, `DocumentID` and `instanceID`, exist in each
 * linked file associated with an InDesign document (.indd). When a link does
 * not contain the aforementioned properties a new one is added.
 * @param {Object} doc - A reference to the .indd to check.
 */
function checkLinksXMP(doc) {
  for (var i = 0, len = doc.links.length; i < len; i++) {

    var link = doc.links[i];
    var linkFilepath = File(link.filePath).fsName;
    var linkFileName = link.name;

    var xmpFile = new XMPFile(linkFilepath, XMPConst.FILE_INDESIGN, XMPConst.OPEN_FOR_READ);
    var xmp = xmpFile.getXMP();

    // Retrieve values from external links XMP.
    var documentID = xmp.getProperty(XMPConst.NS_XMP_MM, 'DocumentID', XMPConst.STRING);
    var instanceID = xmp.getProperty(XMPConst.NS_XMP_MM, 'InstanceID', XMPConst.STRING);

    // Add missing XMP property/values...
    if (!documentID && !instanceID) {
      addDocumentIDAndInstanceID(linkFilepath);
    } else if (!documentID) {
      addDocumentID(linkFilepath, generateUUID());
    } else if (!instanceID) {
      addInstanceID(linkFilepath, generateUUID());
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Update all document links whose state is outdated.
 * @param {Object} doc - A reference to the .indd to update.
 */
function updateOutdatedLinks(doc) {
  for (var i = 0, len = doc.links.length; i < len; i++) {
    var link = doc.links[i];
    if (link.status === LinkStatus.LINK_OUT_OF_DATE) {
      link.update();
    }
  }
}

if (loadXMPLibrary() && linksStatusCheck(doc)) {
  checkLinksXMP(doc);
  updateOutdatedLinks(doc); // <-- Update status after.
}
```

---

**Notes:**

1. Notice how after checking and updating any missing `DocumentID` or `InstanceID` we invoke the `updateOutdatedLinks` function, i.e, see this part in the script:

   ```js
   // ...

   if (loadXMPLibrary() && linksStatusCheck(doc)) {
     checkLinksXMP(doc);
     updateOutdatedLinks(doc); // <-- Update status after.
   }
   ```
2. Also, (as a side note), you can see that in the `checkLinksXMP` function we include the following conditional logic, i.e. this part below:

   ```js
   // Add missing XMP property/values...
   if (!documentID && !instanceID) {
     addDocumentIDAndInstanceID(linkFilepath);
   } else if (!documentID) {
     addDocumentID(linkFilepath, generateUUID());
   } else if (!instanceID) {
     addInstanceID(linkFilepath, generateUUID());
   }
   ```

   Notice how if both `documentID` && `instanceID` are missing, (i.e. the first condition above), we use the same UUID/GUID for both values. Refer to the logic in the `addDocumentIDAndInstanceID` function you can see the same UUID/GUID is shared for both properties.
3. In addition to the above script you will need to add further functionality that saves the changes made to the `.indd` after invoking the `updateOutdatedLinks` function. E.g.

   ```js
   if (loadXMPLibrary() && linksStatusCheck(doc)) {
     checkLinksXMP(doc);
     updateOutdatedLinks(doc);
     doc.save(); // <-- Also ddd this to save the `.indd`
   }
   ```
4. Replace the `generateUUID` function with something that [works cross-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289308/need-to-generate-uuid-for-windows-system-in-extendscript/56473568#56473568).

Comment: Hi RobC,  what I am noticing is only the .indd file which is open in InDesign editor is getting updated. How can I make the the original .indd file  which is located in the folder gets updated with this changes, not just the one opened in the editor? I have used doc.save(), will it save the original file or the copy of it which is opened in InDesign editor?

Comment: The _.indd_ document should be open in _inDesign_ when you run the script. At the end of the script, (i.e after it has completed the task of adding the missing UUID's and updating the modified links), invoke `doc.save()` to save the changes - this will save the original document.

Comment: You could also try replacing `doc.save()` with `doc.close(SaveOptions.SAVECHANGES)` which also save and close the original _.indd_

Comment: Hi RobC, Now for some of the links I am getting status as LINK_EMBEDDED, in that case what I need to do? As per your solution when I am getting status as LINK_OUT_OF_DATE, I am doing link.update(); which is working perfectly fine but now in few cases I am getting the status as LINK_EMBEDDED, in that what I need to do?

Comment: Hi  @MadasuK - Based on your comment - it's unclear to me what you want to do - you should really write a new question and provide more details. However, If the embedded file does actually exist in the file system (presumably it does), then you need to utilize the `Link`'s [`unembed()`](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_Link.html#unembed) method before `update();` . For instance: `if (link.status === LinkStatus.LINK_EMBEDDED) { link.unembed(); } `

Comment: Ok RobC, let me try this, if it did not work out will post a new question.

Comment: @MadasuK - You probably want to change the `updateOutdatedLinks` function to something like [this example](https://paste.ee/p/8xIXZ) instead. However, if I've misunderstood your comment, then please ask a new question and provide further details. Thanks.